# Failure running R CMD BATCH command with PHP

Tags: php, r, mamp, rscript

I'm trying to run R CMD BATCH script from PHP (MAMP) and find the error below:

> R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) -- "Security Blanket" Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for  Statistical Computing ISBN 3-900051-07-0 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)  R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.  dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/x86_64/libR.dylib   Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib  dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/x86_64/libR.dylib   Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

The same command runs perfectly in terminal (MAC OS X 10.8.2).